# perl adding new line after parenthesis

Tags: perl

I have a variable that contents a large texts. I want to add a new line whenever the line has a closing parenthesis.  How do I do that?
This is what I have now without the new line:

```
     foreach $x (@lines) {
     print $x . "\n"; 
     }
```

Thanks!

Comment: My Data looks like :   My Text1 (  some text 2 ) and some text 3;

Comment: Are you not using `strict` and `warnings`?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having?

Comment: It sounds like you need just `$x =~ s/\)/)\n/g`

Comment: There's no need to read the entire file into an array before iterating over the lines, and `$x` is a dreadful identifier for a variable containing a line of text.

Answer (score 0):

It gets a little easier if you use the default, `$_` variable.

```
foreach (@lines) { # For every record in @lines
  s/\)/)\n/g;      # Replace every ")" with ")\n"
  print;           # Print the value in $_
}
```